# На сколько вредно для флеш-памяти часто изменять данные в БД в Android?

Tags: sqlite, память, android

По поводу количества циклов перезаписи флеш-памяти в смартфонах стоит заморачиваться или нет?

Вот допустим Android-приложение, в котором пользователь будет очень часто переносить данные с одной таблицы в другую, сортировать между собой и всякого рода упорядочивать их. В общем будет довольно много мелких запросов к базе для добавления/изменения строк. В день думаю некоторые пользователи до тысячи изменений в базе смогут сделать. Если все эти изменения делать напрямую в базу изо дня в день, то флеш-память у устройства не убьется в скором будущем? Может быть стоит загружать данные из базы в оперативку и работать с ними в оперативке? Или я зря беспокоюсь?

Comment:  1. Вы зря беспокоитесь.
 2. Я бы все-таки оптимизировал, несмотря ни на что, из принципа. :-)

Comment: Сортировка/упорядочивание не должны приводить к перезаписи данных в БД. А если приводят - то вам надо пересмотреть свои подходы.

Comment: @Archi, в любом случае нужные данные стоит архивировать.

Слышали, наверное, старую шутку?

 -- Q: я случайно удалил нужные файлы в \*nix, что делать?

 -- A: нет ничего проще -- восстановите из архива

 -- Q: а если у меня нет архива?

 -- A: значит эти данные на самом деле вам не нужны.

Comment: @Barmaley тогда подход подскажите. К примеру тот же плей-лист в музыкальном проигрывателе, куда пользователь может добавлять новые треки и часто переставлять треки местами. Как обойтись без перезаписи данных, если пользователь захотел трек играющий 10-м сделать играющим первым?

Comment: @Archi такие задачи обычно решаются вообще без БД.
Если между запусками программы плейлисты не надо сохранять, то их и вовсе не надо сохранять (только в опер. памяти во время выполнения). А если надо - то сохраняйте в файл, и кроме того, желательно в какой ни будь стандартный формат (а-ля .pls или .m3u)

Answer (score 1):

Про флешки можно прям в [вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Write_endurance) почитать, или же на [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/17377).
Обычно в районе 100к выдерживает.

Если сравнивать с SSD, то там тоже [в районе 100к](http://www.storagesearch.com/ssdmyths-endurance.html). В лучшем случае 1 миллион. Учитывая, что грохнуть SSD довольно проблематично (даже, если у вас система на этом диске), то о sd-можно не беспокоиться, учитывая, что телефоны нынче всего пару лет живут.

Comment: @Suvitruf, *обычный диск* в Вашем ответе -- это **HDD** (Hard Disk Drive) или **SSD** (Solid State Drive) (про который Вы упоминаете)?

Если SSD, то в чем разница между ним и флеш-памятью?

В любом случае, приведите какие-то ссылки, подтверждающие Ваше заявление:

    Срок жизни флеш-памяти намного больше, чем у обычных жестких дисков

Comment: @avp обновил ответ

Comment: Причем, радикально (упоминание жестких дисков просто исчезло).

Comment: @avp был не прав, каюсь )